# Shell script datetime function?

Tags: shell, date, scripting, ksh

I am running the following script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
./clear_old
./rooms_xls.pl 2/23/09
cd doors
./doors_xls.pl 2/23/09
```

How can I get the date to be today's date based upon the system/server time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(date)`

works

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine (and be almost compliant with your format):

```
#!/bin/ksh
./clear_old
./rooms_xls.pl `date +%D`
cd doors
./doors_xls.pl `date +%D`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks with the date command:

```
./rooms_xls.pl `date +%m/%d/%Y`
```